# How to pass content of variable to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I want to built a calendar that displays events which have are stored in a database. To do this I loop thru a set of records at the beginning of my script and build a string in a variable `vEvents` that ultimately contains this:

```
{ 
   title: 'new appointment', 
   start: '12-OCT-2011 14:00' 
}, 
{ 
   title: 'next appointment', 
   start: '12-OCT-2011 15:00' 
}
```

and so on. So each event is built by information that resides in the DB, the final number of events entries (between the two curly brackets) is unknown and can change dynamically for every call of the calendar.

I'm using a jQuery calendar plug-in (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) which builds the calendar using a jQuery call that goes like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
            },
            editable: false,
            height: 370,
            firstDay: 1,
            weekMode: 'liquid',
            minTime: 8,
            maxTime: 22,
            weekends: false,
            //and now on to the event creation
            events: [
                {
                 title: 'this is a standard event',
                 start: '11-OCT-2011 16:00'
                },
                {
                 title: ' yet another demonstration event',
                 start: '11-OCT-2011 17:00'
                }]
});
```

What I would like to do is to replace anything between the edgy brackets [] in that call by the content of the previously built variable, so something like

```
//and now on to the event creation
events: [
   $(vEvents) // or some other unknown syntax, or an evaluation function etc. that
              // replaces the varibale with it's content at that place
]
```

I have not been able to get that replacement done, I tried the `eval()` function and some other approaches but then jQuery always complains about improper syntax. So is this possible to do overall and if positive how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears as though the `fullCalendar` plugin requires an array of objects. So if `vEvents` looks like this:

```
var vEvents = [//this bracket starts an array
    {//this bracket starts an object
        title: 'new appointment',//this line defines the `title` property of the object it's in
        start: '12-OCT-2011 14:00'//this line defines the `start` property of the object it's in
    },//this ends the current object and the comma separates the two objects as items in an array
    { 
        title: 'next appointment', 
        start: '12-OCT-2011 15:00' 
    }
    //note that there is not a comma here, it's important that commas are only between objects and there is no trailing comma at the end of the list of objects
];//this bracket ends the array
```

Then you should be able to just set the `events` option to the `vEvents` variable like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ...
    //and now on to the event creation
    events: vEvents
});
```

**--UPDATE--**

```
//first, create an empty array
var myEvents = [];

//then iterate through your data
for (var rowIx = 0; rowIx < this.Data.Rows.length; rowIx++) {

    //and add an object, notice the `{` and `}` (brackets) that note the beginning and ending of an object definition
    myEvents.push({title : this.Data.Rows[rowIx][2].text, start : this.Data.Rows[rowIx][5].text;);
}
```

`.push()` adds a value onto the end of an array, so here we `.push()` an object onto an array. `title : this.Data.Rows[rowIx][2].text` adds the `title` property to the new object and maps the value you want to that property.

Comment: He's building a **string** variable. It needs to be json-parsed first.

Comment: I added some comments in my answer about building an array of objects. If he is building the data himself he might as well be doing it correctly right off rather than building it one way and then using another language to fix it.

Comment: Thank you Jasper, but how do I then get the array to be build dynamically? That's why I approached if with a string that "grows" until the loop over the records has finished...Again, I'm new to JavaScript so my questions may seem foolish, I know :-( 

So for example a var 
    myEvents :[
        title: this.Data.Rows[rowIx][2].text, 
        start: this.Data.Rows[rowIx][5].text
    ];

does not seem to work

Comment: Exactly how you do it depends on the server-side language you're using. In PHP I would iterate through the database records and add the title/start-time to an array, then at the end of the loop I would use `json_encode()` to create my array of objects: `$output = array(); while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {$output[] = $row;} echo json_encode($output);` This can also be done without `json_encode()` by just following the guidelines I noted above for creating an array and for creating objects in JavaScript.

Comment: so I tried the follwoing, supposedly creating an array of objects (I thought)
var myEvents = new Array();
var Event = new Array();   
for (var rowIx = 0; rowIx < this.Data.Rows.length; rowIx++) {
myEvents[rowIx] = Event();
myEvents.title = this.Data.Rows[rowIx][2].text;
myEvents.start = this.Data.Rows[rowIx][5].text;}
Question: is this the correct way of doing it in JavaScript? It doesn't seem to work though :-(

Comment: `for (...) {myEvents.push({title:this.Data.Rows[rowIx][2].text, start: this.Data.Rows[rowIx][5].text;})}` I updated my answer with this code.

Comment: Perfect Jasper, that was it. It's working wonderfully :-) Thank you so much for your patience, I truly appreciate it! Regards Stefan

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Hopefully your now-better understanding of arrays and objects will help you find solutions to problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your previously built variable. It's an array, as denoted by square brackets.

```
var myEvents = [
            {
             title: 'this is a standard event',
             start: '11-OCT-2011 16:00'
            },
            {
             title: ' yet another demonstration event',
             start: '11-OCT-2011 17:00'
            }];
```

Here's your calendar setup.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        },
        editable: false,
        height: 370,
        firstDay: 1,
        weekMode: 'liquid',
        minTime: 8,
        maxTime: 22,
        weekends: false,
        events: myEvents
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> To do this I loop thru a set of records at the beginning of my script and build a string in a variable vEvents

Instead of building a string, could you build a JavaScript object?

If not, generate a valid [JSON](http://json.org/) formatted string, and then use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to get a JavaScript object from it.

Keep in mind that `vEvents` should be an array of objects.

Then just use

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: vEvents
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple variable is all you need there. So to test it first do this

```
var vEvents = [
                {
                 title: 'this is a standard event',
                 start: '11-OCT-2011 16:00'
                },
                {
                 title: ' yet another demonstration event',
                 start: '11-OCT-2011 17:00'
                }
              ];

// Calendar code
  ...
  maxTime: 22,
  weekends: false,
  //and now on to the event creation
  events: vEvents });
```

Once you know that works then you can populate the vEvents array dynamically with the data you read from the DB by simply adding it to the array.

Comment: He's building a **string** variable. It needs to be json-parsed first.